# The complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are a Frobenius algebra over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I try to show that there is a functional lineal $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R} $ whose Kernel contains no nonzero left ideals. Define $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(a+bi)=a$ then $f$ is a functional lineal and if $I$ is a ideal on $\mathbb{C}$ with $I\subset Ker(f),$ if $z=a+bi\in I$, then $f(a+bi)=a=0,$ but how I can prove that $b = 0$?

Comment: Think back to the definition of an ideal

Comment: What is the definition of an ideal? If I know what definition you are using, I can tell you whether the answer is easy or not. Also what do you know about the ideals of a field?

Comment: Ok, Since $I$ is ideal, $-b=ibi\in I$ then $f(-b)=b=0.$

Comment: Also, as  $I$ is ideal on $\mathbb{C}$ (fiel) then $I=0$ or $I=\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Literally any nonzero $\Bbb R$ linear functional will automatically work, because there are no nontrivial ideals of $\Bbb C$ to be contained in the kernel.